SQL Server, user's database is not available after boot
We have a kind of strange usage of SQL Server. We develop a client app but due to network issues, each developer is working with his own instance of SQL Server, which by itself is in the container.
So the developing process goes like this:

change code for client application
start container with SQL Server
run unit tests for the application
stop container with SQL Server
repeat

We found that right after the start of container with SQL Server we have a situation
sqlcmd -C -U sa -Q "select @@version"
-- success
sqlcmd -C -U sa -d userdb
-- login failed, no userdb exist
sleep 1
sqlcmd -C -U sa -d userdb
-- success

So apparently, databases (other than master) are loaded by the server after it allows logins with using master as active database.
Is it described somewhere in documentations? Does this behavior differ between versions? We are currently on version 2022 (16.0.4135.4) and I do not remember such issues with earlier ones.

It shouldn't cause complete connection errors like that instead being associated with slow connections as the DB is reopened, but it might be worth making sure that AUTO_CLOSE is not enabled for the affected databases. See this documentation for more details.
Also, it could be that immediately after startup SQL Server is going through the initial roll-forward of transaction log entries in the databases. Do you see the same behaviour with the “ does not exist” if you sleep for a few seconds before the first connection attempt instead of after the first connection?
If you don't get the connection trouble the first time if waiting some seconds before trying to touch  at all, the latter might be what it happening. It may be the case that the container image that you are restoring each time was cut while there was a fair amount in the transactions logs but not yet completely committed to the data files, to mitigate that: restore the image, issue a CHECKPOINT command (see here for more info) & wait for it to finish on all the DBs, stop SQL Server in the container, then remake a fresh image from the result.

We are currently on version 2022 (16.0.4135.4) and I do not remember such issues with earlier ones.

If your current reference image was taken immediately after upgrading to that version, the upgrade process might explain where such transactions which need to be rolled forward each time since have come from.


AUTO_CLOSE=OFF, I just checked.
Transaction log should be empty - one of the benefits of container that all changes to it are rolled back on container shutdown. And no, I do not have login issue if I wait a second after container startup. I'll try to add manual CHECKPOINT command to end of container creation script. But I thought checkpoint are done automatically on server shutdown?
Upgrade of a server is definitely not an issue, since the db for container is created from scripts and no actual version upgrade is taking place.

@WhiteOwl - “benefits of container that all changes to it are rolled back on shutdown”, yes but if there is anything that needs tidying up on start that gets rolled back too and repeated at next start. “But I thought checkpoint are done automatically on server shutdown?”, by default yes, but it can be asked not to do this and if the shutdown/checkpoint request is not synchronous the container may be cut off and snapshotted before the process is complete. As Doug suggests: if it is none of these possible factors, startup time is most likely so a simple delay/retry is all that is needed.

Taking a look at some of my SQL 2019 and SQL 2022 instances, I see a small but non-negligible gap between the time the Master database starts up and the time the last of the user databases starts up. If your attempted connection to userdb happens during this window, that would explain what you are seeing.



SQL instance
SQL version
First record in log
Master starts
Last user db starts
Difference (seconds)




Prod6
SQL 2019
7:09:16
7:09:18
7:09:24
8


Prod5
SQL 2022
6:24:58
6:42:59
6:43:09
10


Prod7
SQL 2022
11:25:37
11:25:39
11:25:46
7



The master database starts within one or two seconds of the first line being written to the SQL log, and the last user database starts (or at least the log says it is starting) around seven to ten seconds later.
The number and size of the databases is likely to affect this, as is the amount of available CPU and RAM, and maybe even the storage I/O performance. And as David's answer says, any needed roll-forward will likely extend this. But even in the absence of any rolling forward, ten seconds is not uncommon.

You confirmed my understanding of the reason for problem. Thanks for that. But is it described in official documentation somewhere?
